# Remove everything after multiple patterns regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to remove the end of strings with three different patterns

Example of strings (this is not a block, these are three independant strings) :

```
BP342
Rue Du Docteur Ichon BP 60 Site de BRESSUIRE
CESEL - Hôtel Dieu 34 Rue du Dr Maunoury - B.P. 30407
```

I wrote this regex pattern to detect each case of `BP` I can get :

```
[B][P]|[[:space:]][B][P]|[-][[:space:]][B][.][P][.]
```

But now I want to delete everything that follows one of each pattern. I tried to put at the end of each pattern `.$` but when I do this, it doesn't recognize anymore the previous pattern. So how do I remove the end of the string after matching the pattern ?

Expected results :

```
(nothing)
Rue Du Docteur Ichon
CESEL - Hôtel Dieu 34 Rue du Dr Maunoury
```

I'm making these examples with this site : https://regex101.com/r/QXYtyv/3

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. Your demo is unrelated to this post.

Comment: BTW, are trying to remove everything after the *first* or *last* `BP` / `B.P.` on the *line* or *string*?

Comment: @anubhava What's unclear and unrelated ? I'm trying to remove everything after `BP`things. I will post an expected results to be more understandable

Comment: @anubhava Oh sorry I didn't give the good link but I have given the correct pattern, you can just copy paste.

Comment: @anubhava Yeah I have edited with the correct demo, sorry. Your example works fine except for the third string from which I want to delete also the `-` before `BP`

Comment: ok then use: https://regex101.com/r/QXYtyv/4

Comment: @anubhava This is what I was searching for, thanks. Could it be possible to explain the `(?:\s*-)?\s` part ? (first time regex).

Comment: That is an optional match of zero or more  spaces and a hyphen.

Comment: @anubhava I see, it's very useful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match using this regex:

```
(?:\s*-)?\s*B\.?P\.?.*$
```

And replace using an empty string.

This regex matches an optional hyphen followed by `BP` with optional DOT in front of both letters. Using `.*$` it matches everything till end of line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QXYtyv/4)